# how to insert multiple array to database using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have  posted values $a,$b,$c...are in array format
 model file i gave this.

```
 function insert_bank_data($da,$b,$c,$d,$e)
    {

        $data=array('date'=>$da,'des'=>$b,'amount'=>$c,'price'=>$d);
        $this->db->insert_batch('total_trans',$data);


}
```

I am getting an error like this.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22' at line 1
```

Comment: Why are you used `;` twice?

Comment: i removed it.still am nt getting

Comment: are $da,$b,$c,$d,$e arrays ?

Comment: yes. these are arrays.when i print_r($a)..i got '30-Dec-2015','30-Dec-2015','29-Dec-2015','28-Dec-2015','...................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if arguments of the function are arrays of the same length you should write

```
function insert_bank_data($da,$b,$c,$d,$e)
{
  $data = array();
  for ($i-0; $i < count($da); $i++) {
    $data[] = array('date'=>$da[$i],'des'=>$b[$i],'amount'=>$c[$i],'price'=>$d[$i]);
  $this->db->insert_batch('total_trans',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode()

```
function insert_bank_data($da,$b,$c,$d,$e)
{

    $data=array('date'=>json_encode($da),'des'=>json_encode($b),'amount'=>json_encode($c),'price'=>json_encode($d));
    $this->db->insert_batch('total_trans',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also...

```
function insert_bank_data($da,$b,$c,$d,$e)
{

    for ($i=0; $i < count($da); $i++) {
        $data= array('date'=>$da[$i],'des'=>$b[$i],'amount'=>$c[$i],'price'=>$d[$i]);
        $this->db->insert('total_trans',$data);
    }
}
```